# ANTLR4 Eclipse Plugin, how to stop the repetitive workspace build

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, antlr4

Have installed AntlrDT and ANTLR4 SDK plugin in eclipse and they are helpful.
Once I write the grammar while and save it it builds the workspace automatically and shows build successful for the grammar .g4 files, which is nice.
But the issue is pit goes on repetitive build, so even if the build is sccuccessful or fail, it again starts building and goes on for infinite time, which is very much irritative.
Is there any option in the plugin to stop the repetitive build process and it only builds when I fire the command or choose the option.
[image]

Comment: The Eclipse in the cropped screenshot looks pretty old. How can the issue be reproduced in a current Eclipse and ANTLR plugin? The project builders are run until no file is modified or touched, so maybe there is a cycle. In _Project > Properties: Builders_ you can (temporarily) disable them, to see which ones cause it.

Comment: @howlger The eclipse I'm using has Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0).  To reproduce the issue, you can just make some changes in your antlr grammar file such that it gives you some error, then you will repetitive build starts. Now, you fix/restore the changes and then save the grammar file. This time the build will be successful, but the repetitive build will continue and it won't stop.

Comment: @howlger As you mentioned, I did checked _Project > Properties : Builders_ , it stopped once I disabled the _Xtext Project Builder_ but then when I am myself selecting the option to build, the build breaks with some antlr error, it seems the _ANTLR Builder_ is dependent on _Xtext Project Builder_ .

Comment: AntlrDT does not use XText, while Antlr4IDE does. Both will, by default, build a `.g4` grammar immediately upon any change. Having both plugins enabled at the same time is not recommended and, if this is the case, is likely the cause of the problem.